# Avoid overlapping of code block on the menu of page

Tags: pelican

I am using Pelican for generation of web pages. However I cannot avoid overlapping of code blacks with the menu list this way.[image]

This the concerned code piece

## General

- Start by reading
  `The Zen of Python <https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/>`_

.. sourcecode:: python

```
import this
```

- For python we have pocket-lint that checks for PEP8 and some other things.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#general .highlight {
    display: flex;
}

#general .highlight pre {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The display mode `flex` allows the contents to rearrange in size and position. By setting this, the bounding box of the surrounding div is pushed to the right, such that background color and border are not overlapping anymore. However, due to the flexible nature of this display mode, the width of the content is reduced to the minimum required. This can be compensated by simply maximizing the width of the element.